# Select Box Validations when using scanner to scan barcode to select option aps classic javascript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have a select box in a classic ASP page that contains barcode values. Users will access the page on an enterprise device that has a barcode scanner. When the page loads it focuses on the select box, and users will scan a barcode to select an item in the list.

my select box looks like the below

```
<select name='barcode' id='barcode'>
<option value='1111'>1111</option>
<option value='2222'>2222</option>
<option value='3333'>3333</option>
<option value='4444'>4444</option>
</select>
```

the problem I am having is if a user scans a barcode that is not in the list (for example a barcode with the value of 5555), but it has the same character length it selects the first item in the list (e.g. scanning barcode of 5555 will have the barcode 1111 selected.

Is there a way that I can catch the value being scanned in, and compare it to the options in the list, and if it doesn't match raise an alert?

I've been stuck on this for over a week and I'm just not coming right. I'm looking for a JavaScript solution if possible as the project is currently done in ASP Classic with JavaScript. I would really appreciate any help or input.

Comment: Closing tag is not the problem. I need to try catch the scanned text value and validate it against the list of option in the select box. Its currently just choosing the first option if the scanned barcode has the same character length as the ones in the list. If I scan a barcode that's not in the list and has less or more characters then nothing is selected.

Comment: maybe something like a hidden text box that gets the scanned value as well, and validate this against the select list, if exists then focus on next element. if not exists alert message and clear value and refocus on select box? Would appreciate any input here, I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the first option value blank, with Scan a barcode as the prompt.

```
<select name='barcode' id='barcode' onkeypress='validate(event, this);'>
<option value='' selected='selected'>Scan a barcode</option>
<option value='1111'>1111</option>
<option value='2222'>2222</option>
<option value='3333'>3333</option>
<option value='4444'>4444</option>
</select>
<input type='hidden' id='bc_entered' />
```

Now include this JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(evt, elem)
{
    var i;
    var match = false;
    var barcode = document.getElementById('bc_entered');

    var evt = evt || window.event;
    var code = evt.keyCode || evt.which;

    if(code == 13) //scanner should append CR
    {
        for(i=0; i<elem.options.length; i++)
        {
            if(barcode.value == elem.options[i].text)
            {
                match = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(match)
        {
            elem.selectedIndex = i;
        }
        else
        {
            elem.selectedIndex = 0;
            alert("Barcode " + barcode.value + " not found!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        barcode.value += code;  //Append the character to hidden field
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempted answer but you clearly didn't read the question

Comment: Sorry I should have read more closely. Check out my edited answer.

Comment: Haven't had a chance to test it yet, but marked it as the answer as it looks like it's what I need. Thank you so much!